# Neovim statusline show filename with minimal setup and without plugin?

Tags: lua, neovim

I would like to configure neovim (0.7.0) with lua, without plugins.

I've configured line number via `vim.wo.number = true`. I guess it would similarly works if I use `vim.o.statusline = "%F"` to let the statusline show file name / path.

However, my neovim's statusline is still empty. How can I change my init.lua, to let the statusline show filepath?

Currently the init.lua is:

```lua
vim.wo.number = true

vim.o.smarttab = true
vim.bo.expandtab = true
vim.bo.shiftwidth = 4
vim.bo.tabstop = 4

vim.o.statusline = "%F"
vim.wo.statusline = '%F'
```

Comment: Please give feedback to people's answers, instead of ignoring them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vim.o.laststatus = 2
```

According to `:help`

```
    The value of this option influences when the last window will have a           
    status line:                                                                   
            0: never                                                               
            1: only if there are at least two windows                              
            2: always                                                              
    The screen looks nicer with a status line if you have several                  
    windows, but it takes another screen line. status-line
```